# Can't change labels in secondary window panel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a secondary window(panel) with a button and a box containing some labels. I need to be able to change the box title and the label text, but can only do so in AwakeFromNIB. If I check a label's text in WindowDidLoad it's nil. Init is firing 3 times.

```
//  ExtendedCal.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface ExtendedCal : NSWindowController
@property (retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *lblCCW;
@property (retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *lblCW;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *lblDegrees;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSBox *boxExtCal;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSButton *btnOK;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *maxSteps;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger arrayCtr;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger steps;

- (IBAction)btnOKClicked:(id)sender;
- (void)resetUI;
@end

//  ExtendedCal.m
#import "ExtendedCal.h"
NSString * const myExtendedCalChangedNotification = @"MyExtCalKey";
NSString *const myExtendedCalEndedNotification = @"myExtCalEndedKey";
NSMutableArray *pointArray;
NSInteger extCalStep;
NSInteger extCalAxis;
NSInteger extCalMin;
NSInteger extCalMax;

/*
@interface ExtendedCal ()
@end
*/

@implementation ExtendedCal

@synthesize lblDegrees;
@synthesize lblCCW;
@synthesize lblCW;
@synthesize btnOK;
@synthesize boxExtCal;
@synthesize maxSteps;
@synthesize arrayCtr;
@synthesize steps;

- (id)init
{
      self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"ExtendedCal"];
      return self;      
}

- (void)windowWillLoad
{
    [lblDegrees setStringValue:@"MMM"]; /// does nothing
}
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];
    NSInteger var1, ec, tmpI = 0;
    steps = 0;
    [self resetUI];  //does nothing when called from here
    maxSteps = @"16";
    ec = 0;
    pointArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    var1 = 0;       
    while (var1 <= extCalStep*25)
    {
        if (extCalMin == var1)
        {
            ec = 1;
            [pointArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:var1]];
        }
        var1 = var1 + extCalStep;
    }
    if(ec==0)
    {
        ec = 1;
        [pointArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:extCalMin]];
    }
    var1 = extCalStep;
    tmpI = [pointArray count];
    while (var1 < extCalMax)
    {
        if (var1 > [[pointArray objectAtIndex:ec - 1]integerValue])
        {
            ec +=1;
            [pointArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:var1]];
        }
        var1 += extCalStep;
    }
    if(extCalMax > [[pointArray objectAtIndex:ec-1]integerValue])
    {
        ec +=1;
        [pointArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:extCalMax]];
    }
    tmpI = [pointArray count];
    arrayCtr = 0;
    NSString *str = [[pointArray objectAtIndex:0]stringValue];

    [lblDegrees setStringValue:str];           //does nothing
    NSString *s2 = [lblDegrees stringValue];   //s2 is nil
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [lblDegrees setStringValue:@"888"];  //works from here
    [self resetUI];                      //works from here
}

- (void)btnOKClicked:(id)sender
{
    extCalStep +=1;
    NSMutableString *tmp;
    NSString *option = @"160";
    tmp = [NSMutableString string];
    [tmp setString:@"Calibration-step "];
    [tmp appendFormat:@"%ld",extCalStep];
    [tmp appendString:@" of "];
    [tmp appendString:maxSteps];
    [boxExtCal setTitle:tmp];         //does nothing
    option = [[pointArray objectAtIndex:arrayCtr] stringValue];
    option = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%ld", extCalStep];
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary 
                 dictionaryWithObject:optionforKey:@"myExtCalKey"];
    [nc postNotificationName:myExtendedCalChangedNotification
                                        object:self
                                userInfo:userInfo];
    steps++;    
}

- (void)resetUI
{
    NSMutableString *boxStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [boxExtCal setTitle:@"Calibration step 1 of 16"];
    lblCW.hidden = NO;
    lblCCW.hidden = YES;
    [boxStr setString:@""];
    [boxStr appendString:@"999"];
    //[boxStr appendString:@"\u00B0"];
    [lblDegrees setStringValue:boxStr];
    steps = 0;
}
```

The wiring

[image]

The window is opened by

```
//  ORSSerialPortDemoController.m

#import "Calibrate.h"
#import "ExtendedCal.h"

Calibrate *calibrate;
ExtendedCal *extCal;
@interface ORSSerialPortDemoController () {
}   
@end
.
.
.
[extendedcal showWindow:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have two instances of your window controller class, `ExtendedCal`. You are creating one in code by allocating and init-ing the class. I suspect you also have one instantiated in the NIB itself. You pretty much confirm this with your self-answer where you mention having Extended Cal in your NIB.

The instance that is created in code is what loads the NIB. It gets the NIB name passed to it when your `-init` method calls super's `-initWithWindowNibName:` method. It loads the NIB when its `window` property is requested for the first time, which is implicit in the call to `-showWindow:`.

When `NSWindowController` (or a subclass) loads a NIB, it passes itself as the owner. So, the File's Owner placeholder in the NIB resolves to that object. Also, the `-windowDidLoad` method is called on that instance.

Since your NIB contained another instance of `ExtendedCal`, that's created, too, when the NIB is loaded. However, it isn't the NIB's owner and it didn't load the NIB. So, it's `-windowDidLoad` method is not called. And any connections to it (outlets, bindings, etc.) do not connect to the first instance.

Having the two instances with separate roles, one of which has certain methods called on it and the other of which has various important connections, is the source of the confusion.

You are correct that changing such connections to connect to the File's Owner is part of the solution. The rest of the solution is to simply remove the instance of `ExtendedCal` from the NIB entirely. It shouldn't be there. The window controller is outside of the NIB. It is created before the NIB is loaded and is, in fact, what loads the NIB. Therefore, it shouldn't be instantiated in the NIB.

For further discussion, I recommend this article: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-04-05-windows-and-window-controllers.html

---

Oh, a few other things:

The NIB is not loaded when `-windowWillLoad` is called. So, no outlets are connected, yet, and `lblDegrees` would be expected to be `nil`.

I recommend avoiding implementing `-awakeFromNib` on a window controller. `-windowDidLoad` is a better choice. The problem with `-awakeFromNib` is that it can be called multiple times under certain circumstances (for example, if your window controller is the delegate for a view-based table view). The semantics and timing of `-windowDidLoad` are just simpler.

Comment: I think you're correct, but I don't understand how/where to remove the instantiation of ExtendedCal from the nib. Resetting the outlets seems to have cured all the ills, but I may be missing something.

Comment: Just select the Extended Cal object in the list of objects in the NIB. You may want to do Editor > Show Document Outline to make it clearer. Once the object is selected, do Edit > Delete to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your care in crafting your answer, and for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Changed all the outlets from Extended Cal to File's Owner, except for window.